# MVC4 and Telerik MVC extension

Tags: telerik

I know telerik already stoped to provide support for their mvc extension.Now Kendo UI comes in.I am currently try to create to project in MVC4 with VS2012.I added telerik MVC extension(Not Kendu UI) from Nuget package manager.I have already done everything for registering telerik and other js file(which i added in my previous project build in MVC3 whcih is runing well).My problem is that client side validation not firing only for telerik control,other html control's client validation is firing.Ony server validation is firing for telerik controls.I try to use Edittor control of telerik but when i browse an image it show me an error from  jquery-1.6.2.js file.What is the problem in MVC4 with previous extisting telerik mvc extension.please leave a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should add below line in _layout.cshtml

@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Scripts(config => config.Add("jquery.validate.min.js").Add("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"))

and make sure that you enable clientsidevalidation in web.config file in appSettings node

Thank you,
[Sandesh Daddi](http://blogs.sandeshdaddi.com)